# Unable to use functions from custom imported module

Tags: ros, rospy, module, function

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,
I'm a novice experimenting on making and using custom modules (python) having functions that is required for my rosnode. I can do the same in normal python, but I am struggling with the import.
After I added the python script in CMakeLists.xml as executable script(python) , import didn't show error.
Edited `CMakeLists.xml` :

```
## Mark executable scripts (Python etc.) for installation
## in contrast to setup.py, you can choose the destination
   catkin_install_python(PROGRAMS
    src/cmdvel_adapterv1.0
    src/server.py
    DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
  )
```

But now, when I try to use any function of `server.py` from `cmdvel_adapterv1.0` :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import server
import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import String


def callback(data):

    ---------


def function():

    port = 8081
    s = server.init_server(port)
   ----
    sub = rospy.Subscriber('cmdvel_socket_stream', String, callback)
    rospy.spin()
    


if __name__ == '__main__':

    try:
        rospy.init_node('cmdvel_adapter_v1_0')
        function()

    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        pass
```

in my rosnode, I get error -

```
    s = server.init_server(port)
AttributeError: module 'server' has no attribute 'init_server'
```

This is the `Server.py` module :-

```
import os
import socket

def dow():
    print("its accessing")


def get_ip():

    ip = socket.gethostname()
    return ip


def init_server(port):

    host = get_ip()
    server = socket.socket()
    server.bind((host,port))
    print('binded to ' + str(host) +':' + str(port))
    return server
```

What am I doing wrong here? This method worked outside ros, why not in ros. Help me.

Thanks in advance
Paul Pavish

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/368896/unable-to-use-functions-from-custom-imported-module/) by [Paul Pavish](https://answers.ros.org/users/62559/paul-pavish/) on ROS Answers with karma: 40 on 2021-01-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2021-01-05**:
Please **edit** your question and add the `CMakeLists.txt`, `setup.py` and source code snippets (of the module and the node). Make sure to only include the relevant parts (remove any unnecessary comments, keep the import and how you call the function, but not the conent).

Thanks.

**Comment by [Paul Pavish](https://answers.ros.org/users/62559/paul-pavish/) on 2021-01-05**:
@mgruhler, Hi there, thanks for the response. I updated the question with your suggested edits with important parts of my code in `CMakeLists.xml` , `server.py` module and my **main code**. Both the Server.py and the main code are in the `~/catkin_ws/src/rospackage/src/` .

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2021-01-05**:
I cannot reproduce that. Please clarify how you run this that you get the error (from devel or install space? Which commands?)

Seems like a name clash to me, but I can only guess. This might depend on what other packages/modules you have installed or in there.

Some general remarks:

- with `catkin_install_python` you should only install executable scripts. those usually should not be included in other files (and should rather be in a directory called `scripts`)
- to me it looks like `server.py` should be a module. If so, set it up as that such that you can `from myrospackage import server`. Have a look [at this doc page](http://docs.ros.org/en/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/installing_python.html) for more information.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-01-05**:\

> with `catkin_install_python` you should only install executable scripts

this is indeed the most likely cause of the problem.

`server.py` should be part of a package. It's not a stand-alone script.

This is also not really ROS-specific (apart from the one Catkin command there).

**Comment by [Paul Pavish](https://answers.ros.org/users/62559/paul-pavish/) on 2021-01-06**:
Thankyou @mgruhler and @gvdhoom , With your keyword suggestions I was able to find a solution.
Again, thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there, I found a solution here : https://roboticsbackend.com/ros-import-python-module-from-another-package/

**edit :**

As mentioned in the blog :
**Step 1:** create a **setup.py** file inside my Package (**myPkg**) folder and posted this code :

```
from distutils.core import setup
from catkin_pkg.python_setup import generate_distutils_setup
d = generate_distutils_setup(
    packages=['myPkg'],
    package_dir={'': 'src'}
)
setup(**d)
```

and just save the file without executing it.

**Step 2:** Create a Folder inside *./myPkg/src/*  with the same name as the pakage (myPkg).

**Step 3:** Go to *./myPkg/src/myPkg/* and Create a new file ****init**.py** and save it as an empty file.

**Step 4:** In the same folder, Create and save the python module files (**myModule.py**) you want to import in your node later. *Note : Make sure to `import rospy` in that module*

**Step 5:** Go back to the package folder *./myPkg/* , open `CMakeLists.txt` and uncomment the line `catkin_python_setup()` and save the file.

**Step 6:** Go back to your catkin workspace folder where myPkg package is, say `cd ~/catkin_ws/` and do `catkin_make`.

Now, if I create a python node in *./myPkg/src/* , I can import **myModule.py** using the line `from myPkg import myModule`.

Tried it, and it worked perfectly for me.

Hope it helps.

---

Originally posted by [Paul Pavish](https://answers.ros.org/users/62559/paul-pavish/) with karma: 40 on 2021-01-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-01-06**:
Link-only answers are highly discouraged.

Could you please post the relevant steps you took as part of your answer?

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2021-01-07**:
@Paul Pavish great that you found a solution. For reference, those steps are basically what is described in the [catkin docs](http://docs.ros.org/en/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/installing_python.html), though there it is more of a text block then a step by step guide.